# Hide Side nav on login page PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I have the following side nav in `side-nav.php`

```
<?php 

if (isset($_SESSION['account'])) {
    $current_user = get_user_on_uin($_SESSION['account']['ein']);
    $current_user = $current_user->fetch_assoc();
}
//show sidebar on everypage except login & graph
  $page_name = basename(__FILE__);
  //var_dump($page_name);
  //die();
if ($page_name != 'login.php' || $page_name != 'graph.php'){

    echo '<div class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
    <li>
    <li>
        <a href="dashboard.php?page_request=request_form"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> Request a Coach</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="dashboard.php?page_request=view_requests"><i class="fa fa-database"></i> View All Requests</a>
    </li>';
    if (isset($current_user) && $current_user['user_role']!='reactive_coach' || $current_user['user_role']!='proactive_coach'){
    echo '<li>
        <a href="dashboard.php?page_request=view_accepted_requests"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> View Accepted Requests</a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="dashboard.php?page_request=view_rejected_requests"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> View Rejected Requests</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="dashboard.php?page_request=view_coach_assigned_requests"><i class="fa fa-binoculars"></i> View Coach Assigned Requests</a>
        </li>';
    }
    echo '<li><a href="dashboard.php?page_request=view_completed_requests"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> View Completed Requests</a>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>';
    if (isset($current_user) && $current_user['user_role']=='reactive_coaching_manager' || $current_user['user_role']=='proactive_coaching_manager' || $current_user['user_role']=='OEM' || $current_user['user_role']=='GM'){
        echo '<li><a href="dashboard.php?page_request=graph"><i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i> Analytics</a>
              </li>';
    }   
    echo '<li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
          </li>';
    echo '</ul>
    </div>

</div>';

}

?>
```

I do not wish to show this `side-nav.php` to appear on `login.php` or `graph.php` pages but it still does...

I tried by successfully getting the current page by:

```
$page_name = basename(__FILE__);
```

But the `if ($page_name != 'login.php' || $page_name != 'graph.php')` seems to be true all the time...

is there a different way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: use `and` instead of `or`  `($page_name != 'login.php' && $page_name != 'graph.php')`

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong operator, it is contradicting itself.

You need to use the `&&` operator instead of `||`

```
if ($page_name != 'login.php' && $page_name != 'graph.php')
```